# How to Implement an edit view for a list of objects in MVC 4 in its most elegant way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a *"ContactInfo"* view in which I want to get a list of different phone numbers of different types from the user. The user should be able to add, edit and delete numbers and specify their types. *At least one mobile number is required.*

I've tried different approaches and I've come to a dead-end at some point. I thought describing the whole scenario and asking for a solution would be more efficient than to ask specific bugs. I'd be thankful for your answers.

Here is my phone class:

```
public partial class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumberType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the phone type enum:

```
public enum PhoneNumberType
{
    None,
    Mobile,
    Home,
    Work
}
```

This is the model for the view (I have also included a list that populates phone types from the enum to fill the type combobox):

```
public class ContactInfoModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<EnumMember> _phoneTypes;
    public IEnumerable<EnumMember> PhoneTypes
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._phoneTypes == null)
            {
                _phoneTypes = EnumUtility.GetEnumMembers(typeof(PhoneNumberType));
            }
            return _phoneTypes;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the view:

```
@model Jobeteria.Models.JobSeekers.ContactInfoModel

@{ViewBag.Title = "Contact Information";}

@using (Html.BeginForm()){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<header class="pages-header">
    <div class="pages-header-bg text-background"></div>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    </hgroup>
</header>
<div class="pages-wide-column">
    <div class="pages-body-bg text-background"></div>
    <div class="pages-content-marginer">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Information</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @*view to manipulate phone numbers*@
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                    <br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
                    <br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Province)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Province)
                    <br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Province)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.County)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.County)
                    <br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.County)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
                    <br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address)
                    <br/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
                </li>
                <li class="horizontal-field">
                    <input type="submit" value="SAVE" />
                    <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript: history.back(1);"/>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

I always find model binding to Enumerable items a bit of a pain - that is essentially what you are trying to achieve right, allow the user to edit a list of phone numbers?.

In terms of validation, I would write a custom validation attribute to use in your View Model - this will check that at least one phone number is present.

Phil Haack has bloged about binding to lists here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Adapting from Phil's post I think you will have to do something like this:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < userPhoneNumeberCount; i++) { %>

  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phones[i].Number ) %>
  <%: Html.SelectListFor(m => m.Phones[i].Type, PhoneNumberSelectListData ) %> 
<% } %>
```

Comment: Phil Haack wrote this code in 1902 and I keep stumbling on it. MVC5